# Cambiar un numero en formato Character a Numeric

Tags: r

Tengo datos como los dos siguientes (en diferentes columnas) en formato character y busco poder cambiarlos a numericos.
Intento con la formula `as.numeric` aplicando un `gsub` interno para reemplazar la coma o punto depende el caso, pero siempre termino con todos valores NA
Gracias de antemano.

| Volumen | Efectivo |
| --- | --- |
| 14.262.212 | 134.430,40 |

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código en donde intentas resolverlo?, donde te da de resultado NA. Por favor

Comment: Lo intente y me percate que la formula `as.numeric` da el resultado deseado pero si no existiera el segundo punto o la coma **(.212, 0,40)**

Comment: Justamente con eso mismo tengo complicaciones. No se qué se puede hacer con esa formula cuando hay dos puntos en el dato, o punto y coma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pareciera que en tu caso la `,` es separador decimal y el `.` de miles, para poder convertir estos datos habría que (a) eliminar los puntos (b) reemplazar la coma por un punto. Por ejemplo, puedes usar `gsub()` para hacer los reemplazos:

```
cadena <- '134.430,40'
cadena <- gsub(',', '.', gsub('[.]', '', cadena))
cadena

[1] "134430.40"

as.numeric(cadena)

[1] 134430.4
```

En tu caso podrías hacer algo así:

```
as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', gsub('[.]', '', df$Volumen)))
as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', gsub('[.]', '', df$Precio)))
```

Comment: Aplico la formula que me pasaste para ambas columnas pero ahora los datos figuran con una parte subrayada. ¿Estará ocurriendo algo al quitar los puntos? De todas maneras reviso los datos y figuran como numericos. Debe ser un error de mi sistema nomas.

Comment: Raro.. cualquier cosa agrega un ejemplo de los datos originales en tu pregunta con la salida de `dput(head(tu_df))`